# Close multiple windows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using `window.open` in JavaScript to open multiple windows, the pop up opens same application, now I want to close multiple windows on close of any open window, I am using an array to store the window object, the problem is I am getting the updated array only on the last opened window, but not on the windows opened previously, so when I close the last window it closes all the windows but when I open any window in between it will not close all the windows because the updated array is not there on the page.

Is there any way to close all windows that is to get the updated array on the previous pages,
I have searched through the net but am not able to find the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need this functionality but I don't think opening multiple popups is a proper solution, whatever your application is requiring. I think you need to find another way for solving your problem. I suggest using [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) plugin, then you can close all of your opened dialogs pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the multiple windows from the same page (lets say master.html) then you can maintain the array object in the master.html and keep updating the array object on every window open by either on the click event of the link or $(document).ready() event of the child window. You can refer the the array object of master.html from child page as Parent.arrWindow[Parent.mCounter++] (assuming arrWindow is the array object and mCounter is the counter variable defined in master.html). Now on close event of any child page, you can refer the same array object and close all the other child windows. Hope I have understood your problem correctly and addressed it.

You can use the following javascript code as reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var abcd = "Hello";
    var myParent = null;

    function openWindow(){
        window.open("anypage.html");
    }

    $(document).ready( function () {
        myParent = window.opener;
        while(myParent != null || myParent != undefined) {
            alert(myParent.abcd);
            myParent = myParent.opener;
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnWindowOpener" value="Click Me" onclick="openWindow();">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I can open a new window from the child window also and all are same applications

Comment: In that case, you can write a recursive function to refer to the ultimate parent page and once you have the object of ultimate parent page, you can update the array object of it and similarly create another recursive function to get the updated array object of ultimate parent page and close all the child windows. Hope this works.

Comment: Plz see me my answer above. Have added a code snippet for your reference.

Comment: thanks again, but I am still not getting window.opener because my parent window is the frame, when checked parent windows name it shows frame name

Comment: @EricIlavia, Can you share some code (in your question above) to show how you have implemented it as that will surely help me solve your problem.

Comment: <frameset border="0" rows="74,*">
  <frame name="myname" id="myid" SCROLLING="no" src="myjsp.jsp" noresize >
  <frame name="main"  src="otherjsp.jsp" ></frameset><noframes></noframes> ,now this is the frame code , in this myjsp.jsp has link which open this same frameset, which can be opened multiple times , I want to close those opened windows, whos window.opener i am getting null